# YesNo box won't terminate code when selecting "No"

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a macro to have a box prompt to confirm the action like "Do you want to clear the sheet?" with a yes or no question.
If YES, to delete the given cells 
If NO, do nothing.

The YES condition works. But I can't seem to make the NO work. Even if I click on NO, it still executes the clear command. What am I doing wrong?

I'm not well versed in coding. I simply rely in Google. I have tried to change the "else" to "End if" and also tried "then" but none works. I'm not sure how to stop the code from running.

```
function myFunction() {
var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=sh1.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=sh.alert("Clear?",sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO)

  if(response.YES);{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('b1:b21').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C13:C18').clearContent();
  }
  Else {}
}
```

Even clicking NO from the prompt it still executes the clearContent command.

Comment: I tried it with. Still does the same thing :( @KenWhite

Comment: See my answer. There was  more to the issue than the misplaced `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `response` correctly. It contains a `UI.Button.YES` or `UI.Button.NO` value. The correct test would be

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = sh1.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = sh.alert("Clear?", sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO)

  if(response == UI.Button.YES) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    sheet.getRange('b1:b21').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('C13:C18').clearContent();
  }
}
```

For more information, see the documentation for [UI.Alert](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,String,ButtonSet))

(You also had a misplaced `;` in your original code after the `if()`, with `if(response.YES);{`, which my answer removes as well.)

Comment: Thank you @ken white ...This worked out good. I just needed to change the   `if(response == sh.Button.YES ) {` and it worked!